# Visual Studio 2017 Linux debuging child process of foreign executable

Tags: linux, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a gcc plugin with the support of Visual Studio 2017s Linux remote programming.
Here is an screenshot of the debugger configuration:

[image]
As you can see, there is nothing special.
Because g++ is executing the program `/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.2.0/cc1plus` as an new process I checked the `Debug Child Process` option, so gdb should debug cc1plus and thus my plugin.

The program is working absolutly fine, I may run it with the debugger of Visual Studio and the program exits with code 0.

But there is some strange behaviour:

1. The program always stops in `ld-linux-x86-64.so` with the `message Unknown stopping event`:
   [image]
2. After clicking [image] my breakpoints in the .so seems to get loaded. I'm assuming this because the breakpoint circles [image] getting fullfilled [image] and because I'm getting these messages:
   [image]
   So Visual Studio hits some of the breakpoints I set, but the debugger isn't stopping there
3. After those messages the error in 1. happens again, after hitting [image] the program terminates normally.

So why Visual Studio doesn't break at my breakpoints?